# Center the camera view

Tags: 3d-view

Is there any way to center the camera view with either a command or with python?
I know I can shift + middle mouse drag to bring it back to the center but I want to make a add-on (not for this...), where it is important that it is in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

View :: Cameras :: Frame Camera bounds

also: Home key

[image]